# Access Violation during planning of Fourier Transform

Tags: c++

Little bit of background, I'm more experienced with Java, and have some C/C++ experience.
I'm using Visual Studios 2010.

I created two classes inside a header file and gave them fields.
It compiles ok, and for the longest time it was running just fine.
I copied the entire project directory to a new folder (all files inside) and simply recompiled and ran it.  Now whenever I run it I get "Unhandled exception at 0x637779ab in RegistrationExpLib2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000." At this line

```
FourierTrans[i] = fftwf_plan_dft_2d(imgRows, imgCols, in[i], out[i], FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);
```

I checked the debugger, and all of the class fields return could not evaluate expression.
I've already checked and the image is being read in correctly.  And as far as I can tell All of the memory has been allocated correctly.  fftw3 is a C dll I'm linking against.
So I'm really puzzled and was hoping someone could point out a possible issue.  I'm thinking its either, I'm doing something wrong with the set up when I copied the Visual Studios Project(Even though I didn't change anything since it was working), or I've incorrectly allocated memory in the header.  Another issue I thought of is each image is about 20MB, so I may be messing with the heap. 
I really appreciate any help.

The Images being read in are frequently 10-20MB apiece.  The code is compiled as a 32 bit binary.

This is the relevent simplified portion of the code that produces the crash.

```
#define TESTNUM 80

//A simple test main.
int main() {
   ComplexImageFFTW a;
   ComplexImageFFTW b[TESTNUM];
   ComplexImageFFTW* ptrB;
   ptrB = b;

   printf("start\n");
   a.readImage("imagefile1", true);
   printf("Mission\n");
   for(int i = 0; i < TESTNUM; i++) {

          b[i].readImage("imagefile2", true);
   } 
   //Crash occurs here.
   FourierTrans[i] = fftwf_plan_dft_2d(imgRows, imgCols, in[i], out[i], FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);
         ...
} //End main
```

Comment: Why not reduce this code before posting it?

Comment: Can you provide a *minimal* code sample that still crashes?

Comment: Check your pointers. At least one is NULL, where it should not be.

Comment: Without deep-diving into all this code, my bet is that your threads aren't synchronized properly. The error says you're trying to write to a NULL pointer. Is it possible some thread does that before the pointer is being set? Race conditions are a good reason for code to start failing when some changes are made.

Comment: You might try refactoring this a bit and maybe that will help you find the problem.  You really need to strive to adhere more to SOLID and DRY principles. This would make it easier for us to help you and for you to help yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I'll cut it up a bit, I added quite a few pieces which weren't involved.  Especially the multithreading part, that hasn't even started yet.  And for the design, slowly been making it smoother, its been a work in progress, trying to implement an algorithm, its a bit complex but I'll try to do what I can to clean it up.

Comment: I've discovered that when I reduce the number of images from 80 to 75 it doesn't crash anymore.  Given that they are 22 megabytes apiece, and it adds up to 1.7 gigs of memory being used, could it be that I'm overwriting my own heap?

Comment: Are you are aware that if `malloc` fails to allocate memory on the heap, it returns a null pointer? Do you check the pointers provided by `malloc` before you write to them?

Comment: I was not aware of that.  I'll check for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Access violation writing location 0x00000000` means that you're trying to write to memory location `0x00000000`, i.e., you're writing to a null pointer. I think the pointer `p` probably has the value 0.

Possibly you're forgetting to call your `Registration::setUpRegistration` method?

Comment: Let me clean this up a bit, I didn't realize how crazy it looked until I put it here.  the class Registration isn't being used at this point.  As for p, it may be null, I allocated it in Register, with 'fftwf_plan p[NUMTHREADS];'

Answer (score 1):

After reading in the 80 plus images.  The amount of Heap used was >1.7GB.  Since this was compiled as a 32bit binary there are memory limitations of about 2GB. when the program went to plan the Fourier Transform it resulted in a failed memory allocation, which creates a null pointer.  Then the program went to use the pointer, unchecked, resulting in an access violation error.